# Attempt to pass Variable to textView - PointerException

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Why it keeps throwing this pointer exception - I assume the custom layout has no problem. Would anyone tell me what is the wrong with my textview that I defined inside onCreate method. Yes am reading withing the Recall Button from text file and calling method for analysis the data, but am struggling in displaying the results in textview at same time. what is the wrong for that? am I blocking the UI? thank you in advance,and i know.. so don't tell me Nullpointer is repelciate question. Best

```
 TextView Peaks_num;
  @overide
  onCreate(){
   .....
   .....
 //Read data.
    Recall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Recall);
    Recall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

         String line = null;

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             List<Integer> List_Of_Peaks = findPeaks(String_TO_List);
            Dialog mdialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            mdialog.setTitle("MyDialog");
            mdialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog);
            mdialog.show();
             Peaks_num = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Peak_Num);

             Peaks_num.setText(String.valueOf(List_Of_Peaks));


          }
        });



   //my custom layout that should to be for the textview inside the dialog. 
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Peak_Num"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1.7dp"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:text="Peaks"
    android:textColor="#040307" />

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="@string/textView_Peaks_index"
        android:id="@+id/text_Index"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `Peaks_num = (TextView) mdialog.findViewById(R.id.Peak_Num);`

Comment: If that doesn't solve the problem then post the stacktrace from the crash and I will reopen. But almost certain that's your issue

Comment: It did solve my issue. Thanks so much